# How to remove goop/slime from powdered tomato soup?

Tags: texture, consistency

I bought "Professional Tomato Soup Mix" and it comes out slimy when prepared according to package instructions. Specifically, after 10 minutes cooling, a film forms on the surface. When stirred, the film does not dissolve, and instead separates into slimy clumps, a bit like snot.

I don't know what causes it but I think it's the modified starch.

> **Ingredients:** Potato starch, sugar, tomato puree powder, salt, yeast extract, maltodextrin, palm fat, sunflower oil, glucose syrup, onion powder, citric acid, flavourings, modified starch, pepper, beetroot juice concentrate.
>
> **Directions:**
>
> 1. Ensure the product is well mixed before weighing out.
> 2. Stir the required amount of soup mix into cold water.
> 3. Bring to the boil, while stirring.
> 4. Simmer for approximately 4 minutes, whisking occasionally.
> 5. For best results, whisk thoroughly before serving.

Is there some sciencey way to prevent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the kind of stuff I call "instant goop".

The only way to deal with it is not let it sit still long enough to skin over - keep whisking every minute, or make it closer to serving time.

Once it skins, you could see if a paper towel will pick it off in almost one piece. Otherwise you'll just have to punch a hole in it, ladle through the hole & try not to get any in the bowl. You're basically fighting a losing battle with it, as the skin will thicken over time.

[btw, in the UK, you wouldn't be allowed to sell that as 'tomato soup'. Even instant 'cup a goop' is more than 50% tomato.]